# magento2 addtocarturl problem in form action of product listing page

Tags: magento2, custom, frontend

I had uploaded the product via XL using my custom module for simple and bundle products.

product is uploaded successfully and I check all the details on admin product page and DB tables.

ON FRONT END
But addtocarturl is coming worng on form action on product list page.